# How to get URL string parameter

Tags: javascript

Actually I am a student and a beginner
I am making a online wish webpage as a test project And I want to display the sender's name in html
I have successfully completed with that but I want to get the URL string parameter text
How can I do it

My website address pattern is like
www.subdomain.domain.tld/page/?n=(sender_encoded_name)

So I want to fetch data from n parameter of the URL and decode it.

I had searched alot online regarding this and got confused
So please help me with the actual method

I tried using this code,

```
var reqParam = URLDecoder.decode(reqParam, "UTF-8")
```

but I am a little bit confused do please help me as necessary...

Comment: They are called `query string`. Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: I sawed I before but I am confused as the code is using multiple query strings
Please help me

Comment: You've tagged several languages. Narrow it down to the one you actually need help in.

Comment: Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can try it for getting query parameter values-

```
var urlObj = new URL("http://www.subdomain.domain.tld/page/?n=a%20b%20c&m=a%20b%20c%20d");
var params = urlObj.searchParams;
params.get('n');
params.get('m');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use Pattern Matching with a Regular Expression to gather the data you want from the URL String (or any string for that matter):

```
String urlString = "www.subdomain.domain.tld/page/?n=(sender_encoded_name)";

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String regexString = "\\Q?n=(\\E(?s)(.*?)\\Q)\\E";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?iu)" + regexString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlString);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group(1).trim();
    list.add(match);
}

// Display all items found matching the supplied pattern
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Console output will be:

```
sender_encoded_name
```

To put this into a method you might have:

```
public List<String> getEncodedName(String urlString) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String regexString = "\\Q?n=(\\E(?s)(.*?)\\Q)\\E";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?iu)" + regexString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group(1).trim();
        list.add(match);
    }
    return list;
}
```

And to use it:

```
String urlString = "www.subdomain.domain.tld/page/?n=(sender_encoded_name)";
List<String> list = getEncodedName(urlString);

// Display all items found matching the supplied pattern
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Console output will be:

```
sender_encoded_name
```

Regular Expression Explanation:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think, you will find interesting this page:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

An example that maybe can help you in PHP:

```
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['name' ]) . '!';
```

Imagine that your URL is `http://example.com/?name=Andrew`

Then, you will see something like: `Hello Andrew!`